# Gitlab multi-container pod with Helm Charts

Tags: docker, kubernetes, gitlab-ci, kubernetes-helm

How to package 2 Gitlab projects as a pod in a CI/CD pipeline and deploy via helm charts. It's easy to do if one project one pod, but how to link multiple Gitlab projects to the pipeline ?

The other issue is how to know the current version of image2 if pipeline 1 knows only the version of the current app build, not the second one which is currently running inside the pod.

Comment: It’s trivial to write two separate Deployment YAML files.  What have you done so far?  What practical problems are you running into?

Comment: I have project A with looks at project helms (has all the helm charts definitions for all apps in it). Project B also looks at Projects Helms finds the appropriate helms charts by name (Project B) and uses that for deployment.  Pipeline uses the Project name to identify which helm chart from Project Helms to use to deploy an application. This is good and nice for single container/projects apps. But what is the best practice if I need to package multiple container into a pod ? If you run project A or B in this case both need to package container A&B into one pod.

Comment: Best practice is almost always to run one container in a pod if you can manage it; if you need a second container it’s usually something like a logging sidecar.  You could set up a pipeline that builds A and pushes it to a registry, builds B and pushes it to a registry, then does one deploy, if you really needed that.